# New to SQL, getting "Error while executing SQL query on database 'flowers2019': no such column: SIGHTINGS.PERSON" When I try to test my trigger

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

I am trying to make a trigger that only lets me add a new PERSON if they are already included in the database.  For example I can add a new entry for Donna, but not Joe because he's not in the database.

Table:
SIGHTINGS

```
NAME                    PERSON          LOCATION                 SIGHTED
Alpine columbine    Donna           Chula Vista Campground   2006-07-03
Alpine columbine    Jennifer    Bright Star Mine     2006-07-11


CREATE TRIGGER validate_name
   BEFORE INSERT ON SIGHTINGS
BEGIN
   SELECT
      CASE
    WHEN NEW.PERSON NOT IN SIGHTINGS.PERSON THEN
         RAISE (ABORT,'Error: Insert into the SIGHTINGS table references a person that is not found in the database.')
       END;
END;
```

My tests:

```
INSERT INTO SIGHTINGS VALUES ("Douglas dustymaiden", "Joe", "Double Mountain", "2008-11-28")

and

INSERT INTO SIGHTINGS VALUES ("Douglas dustymaiden", "Donna", "Double Mountain", "2008-11-28")
```

For both tests I get Error while executing SQL query on database 'flowers2019':

> no such column: SIGHTINGS.PERSON.

I apologize if this is an stupid question, I am brand new to SQL.

Comment: I'm not familiar with sqlite but normally you would do something more like: where NEW.PERSON not in (select PERSON from SIGHTINGS). This would check for the existence of a matching value in the whole of that column. You can also a not exists clause if your database supports it too. If you need 'when' instead of 'where' for your database then you can amend accordingly.

Comment: This worked perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The clause :-

```
WHEN NEW.PERSON NOT IN SIGHTINGS.PERSON THEN
```

[image]

Is trying to access a table named PERSON in the attached database that has a schema name of SIGHTINGS, if that were to exist then it is effectively creating NOT IN  (SELECT * FROM PERSON).

As per :-

- > The right-hand side of an IN or NOT IN operator can be a table name or table-valued function name in which case the right-hand side is understood to be subquery of the form "(SELECT * FROM name)".
- [SQL As Understood By SQLite - expression - The IN and NOT IN operators](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)

What you probably want to use is :-

```
WHEN NEW.PERSON NOT IN (SELECT PERSON FROM SIGHTINGS)
```

- > The IN and NOT IN operators take an expression on the left and a list of values or a subquery on the right.
- [SQL As Understood By SQLite - expression - The IN and NOT IN operators](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)

So you probably want :-

```
CREATE TRIGGER validate_name
   BEFORE INSERT ON SIGHTINGS
BEGIN
   SELECT
      CASE
    WHEN NEW.PERSON NOT IN (SELECT PERSON FROM SIGHTINGS)
         RAISE (ABORT,'Error: Insert into the SIGHTINGS table references a person that is not found in the database.')
       END;
END;
```